# RGBD-SLAM on Windows 7

Tags: slam, action, ros-fuerte, rgbd-slam, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm looking to complete a similar project to the RGBDSLAM competion entry. The differences being that I will be using the ASUS Xtion pro and I am looking to complete the project on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010.

Is it possible/practicle to apply the source code found at https://openslam.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/data/svn/rgbdslam/ on the Windows platform? I am especially concerned with Diamondback.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36318/rgbd-slam-on-windows-7/) by [BrowCam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2597/browcam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-04-20**:
Hi ! I'm also interested, Did you manage to find it how compile the source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Windows support is not the best. You can find information for it [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Windows).

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0